# cmake - reference build type in custom target command?

Tags: cmake

In cmake, is there a way to reference the build type inside a custom target's command? I need my project to kick off another build, but its command line needs a "debug" or "release" on it in order to tell that build to use the same build type that my main project is being built with.

From what I can tell, the custom target's commands under Xcode are stuffed into a makefile, and that makefile doesn't have a way to know whether it's doing a debug or release build.

In Visual Studio, the custom target's commands are put into a custom build step, so I can use $(Configuration) to get this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from cmake 2.8.3 you can use `$<CONFIGURATION>` inside the custom commands to reference active configuration:

```
add_custom_target(mytarget
  ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/some.py" --configuration $<CONFIGURATION> )
```

I have not used it with XCode but it works fine with Visual Studio and make.

Answer (score 1):

What i can suggest is setting some variable depending on CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE and passing it into add_custom_command as it's argument.

The other way is to create custom commands inside `if(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX STREQUAL "...")` clause.